# MERGE INTO update failure

Tags: sql, oracle

I have two queries. One returns this output:

```
SQL > select * from TableA

id | stable |    a    |    l    |    N    |  user   |   date  |  Ouser  |  Odate |
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
x  | aa     |   GHUA  |   0000  |   1000  |  userA  |   1223  |  userA  |   1223  |
y  | bbb    |   GHUA  |   1111  |   2000  |  userB  |   1223  |  userA  |   1223  |
z  | ccc    |   GHUA  |   2222  |   3000  |  userC  |   1223  |  userA  |   1223  |
```

The other returns this:

```
SQL > select * from TableB

id | stable |    a    |    l    |    N    |  user   |   date  |  Ouser  |   Odate |
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
A  | abe    |   GHUA  |   3000  |   4100  |  userD  |   1224  |  userB  |   1223  |
B  | aa     |   GHUA  |   0000  |   1100  |  userC  |   1224  |  userC  |   1223  |
C  | bbb    |   GHUA  |   1111  |   2100  |  userD  |   1224  |  userD  |   1223  |
D  | ccc    |   GHUA  |   2222  |   3300  |  userE  |   1224  |  userE  |   1223  |
```

========================================================================

I want to use `merge into` to change TableA with the data from TableB ,but always update/Insert failure.

Could someone give some advice for me?

```
merge into TableA d 
      using TableB s 
         on (trim(d.stable) = trim(s.stable) and trim(d.a) = trim(s.a) and 
trim(d.l) = trim(s.l)) 
when MATCHED then 
        update set (d.n = trim(s.n),d.user= s.user,d.date= s.date)
        when NOT MATCHED then 
           insert (ID,stable,a,l,n,user,date,Ouser,Odate)
           values(ID,stable,a,l,n,user,date,Ouser,Odate);
```

Comment: *"but always update/Insert failure."* For future reference please include the error message in such posts. I had to generate the DDL and DML statements to create your base tables before I could run your code and find out the error. Many people won't have the time and/or patience to do that, so you are reducing the pool of people available to help you.

Comment: I strongly concur with apc. Telling us that you get an error, but not telling us the whole error message, is extremely unhelpful. Imagine if you ran your code the error message said "it's broken, that's all I'm saying, it's broken"?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When I ran your code it hurled this error:

> ORA-01747: invalid user.table.column, table.column, or column specification

This is because you have erroneously wrapped the SET clause in brackets. You need to remove them.

Having done that the code hurls:

> ORA-38101: Invalid column in the INSERT VALUES Clause: "D"."ID"

This is because your source and target tables have the same projection, so the column names in your INSERT statement are defined ambiguously. You may wish to argue that the compiler ought to know that columns in the INSERT() projection refer to `tableA` and columns in the VALUES() projection refer to `tableb`. Whatever, we have to obey the compiler. So you need to qualify the column names.

This version of your code works:

```
merge into TableA d 
      using TableB s 
         on (trim(d.stable) = trim(s.stable) 
         and trim(d.a) = trim(s.a) 
         and trim(d.l) = trim(s.l)) 
when MATCHED then 
        update 
        -- remove unnecessary brackets
        set d.n = trim(s.n)
             ,d.usr= s.usr
             ,d.dt= s.dt 
when NOT MATCHED then 
        -- alias all the columns
        insert (d.ID,d.stable,d.a,d.l,d.n,d.usr,d.dt,d.Ouser,d.Odate)
        values (s.ID,s.stable,s.a,s.l,s.n,s.usr,s.dt,s.Ouser,s.Odate);
```

Comment: Qualify, not alias ;)